# How to write an Hello world driver for linux

Tags: c, linux, embedded, driver, linux-device-driver

Recently I'm much excited about linux. I would like to learn how to write simple linux drivers.I know C and python . I'm using ubuntu 11.10 (3.0.0-12-generic kernal).

My Doubts

1. What are the requirements to need to develop and study simple linux driver programs
2. I see may tutorials.But that all are not good in beginner level.Could you please suggest  a better tutorial exactly for beginners.
3. How compile , run and see whether my driver is working.

Comment: not sure if this is what you are looking for: [Writing Device Drivers in Linux](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux). Generally, there are lots of tutorials out there. You might also want to look at [FPGA4Fun](http://www.fpga4fun.com/PCI6.html) tutorial. Although it is more FPGA oriented, the PCI driver outline is really neat.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to start learning devise driver in my system(3.0.0-12-generic kernal). What are the fundementals I need to install)

Comment: And after you're done with the tutorial you can read "Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Ed" online or by PDF download (it has a Creative Commons license): http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/ or http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ or http://free-electrons.com/doc/books/ldd3.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the following link. It contains example of developing kernel linux char driver

http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x569.html

If you want to start kernel developing from the beginning then start the tutorial from the beginning

http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/index.html

to build your kernel module use the Makefile:

```
obj-m += module1.o

all
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Sir could you please suggest me an hello world driver program

Comment: In the first link you find cherdev.c is a hello world char driver for linux. But I advice you to follow the tutorial fro the beggining (second link)

Comment: Sir is this development possible in my ubuntu 11.10 (3.0.0-12-generic kernal)

Comment: your kernel is 3.0. and the links I gave to you are bout kernel 2.6. I m not familiar with the kernel 3.0. but let's assume this code works for 3.0. and if you meet any problem in this code with your linux kernel please back to the stack overflow

Comment: 3.0 isn't VERY different from the 2.6 - you may think it is because there's a big gap in numbers, but they changed the versioning number to not have so many parts in a version number when moving from 2.6.something to 3.0.

Comment: sir what are the steps needed to compile hello world program http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x121.html    in my kernal. What are the changes i need to malke to run my hello world driver

Comment: Otherwise he can install a small linux (with kernel 2.6) just for test. For example he can install openwrt linux from openwrt.org on a virtual machine. and then try his hello module with openwrt

Comment: @Unais I update the answer it contains now how to build your kernel module